# How to pass variable from one php page to the next

Tags: php, google-maps

What I'm trying to do seems very simple, but I can't quite figure it out because every single example I see only has to do with a login or sign up page. I am using Google Maps API v3, there are variables called `event.latLng.lat` and `event.latLng.lat`. I would like to have a link that will send you to the next page and simply display the lat and lng. The second page is called second.php.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
nextpage.php?lat=12&lng=34
```

This may be retrieved on the next page with `$_GET['lat]` and `$_GET['lng]`.

You see all variables passed to a page via `GET` in the `$_GET` superglobal, e.g.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variable to the second page in many different ways:

**1. pass variables with POST or GET**

```
<a href='second.php?lat=12&lng=34'>Second Page</a>
```

On the second page you can retrieve those values with

```
$_GET['lat'];
$_GET['lng'];
```

**2. cookies.**

```
setcookie("lat", 12);    
setcookie("lng", 34);
```

On the second page you can retrieve the value with

```
$_COOKIE['lat']
$_COOKIE['lng']
```

**3. sessions**

Or you can store sessions variables:

```
   $_SESSION['lat']=12;
   $_SESSION['lng']=34;
```

and just retrieve on the second page with:

```
   $lat = $_SESSION['lat'];
   $lng = $_SESSION['lng'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those are JavaScript variables, not PHP.  To pass PHP variables using GET is relatively straightforward:

```
<a href = "page.php?lat=<?php echo(urlencode($lattitude)); ?>&long=<?php echo(urlencode($longitude)); ?>">
    Click Here!
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like what fdomig said,

```
<a href="nextpage.php?late=12&lng=34">Go to next page</a>
```

and to retrieve the variables in the next page

```
<?php

$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];

?>
```